# mysqlnd gives 'permission denied' for all connections to a remote host

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, selinux

This is not about 'localhost'.  Both the command line version of 'mysql' as well as a script I wrote in Perl (using perl-DBD-MySQL) can login, get to this database and work with it.  Only PHP gives the permission denied error, and that error is not reported in any of the various log files.  I even went as far as creating a simple test user in the database to avoid any issues with special characters in the password:

create user 'web'@'%' identified by 'Iamnotarobot';

and again the command line can login with this credential but PHP says permission denied.

I don't know what is throwing the error so I can't address it.  I'm literally lost.
Relevant info:
RHEL 8 = 4.18.0
php 7.2.11
nginx 1.14.1

And here's the actual code that's failing:

```
<?php
$host="core";
$user="web";
$pass="Iamnotarobot";
$db="mydb";

$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if( $conn->connect_errno ) {
  exit($conn->connect_errno);
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you on the right port, maybe start your server on another port and add that port to your request.

Comment: You did read the part about how other things can get to that same database?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an selinux issue.  Here's how I fixed it:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Now with `setenforce` back to '1', the page can connect to the database.

Answer (score -1):

Check with php-mysql package installation.

If perl can connect remotely and php could not...the issue is with php-mysql installation only.

Comment: the Mysql command line tool and perl can connect to that same database on that same host from this machine.  So yes this has to be a php-mysqlnd and or php-fpm issue.

Comment: If you had tried re-installing php-mysql modules...you shall try another probability too.

Comment: SELinux might be hindering in the sense that if any of your file permissions (including the web log files, /etc/httpd or apache2). Check **ls -l -Z** for all relevant files under /etc/ /log/ etc. Or else issue **setenforce 0** and then check the same through php. Because web log files (and some of /etc/ files) are to be accessed for php to run and not for mysql command line and perl script run from bash (except cgi-bin perl scripts)

Comment: I'm currently on version 4 of the system and I have the perl working.  I haven't installed anything related to serving web pages as yet but once I do I'll give the setenforce thing a try.  Actually I think it's going to turn out to be something like selinux.